# Instanciar obejtos al hacer click con el ratón en unity 3d

Tags: c#, unity3d

este es mi primer juego con unity. Es algo bastante simple, pero no estoy consiguiendo que me salga. La idea sería que al hacer click en cualquier parte de la pantalla de instancie un objeto.
Desde ya muchas gracias por su ayuda! Este sería el código que tengo hasta ahora:

```
`using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class game_cont : MonoBehaviour
{
    public GameObject bar;
    public float lar;
    int newpos = 0;
    Collider[] thebox;

    
    void Start()
    {
        newpos = 0;
    }

    
    void LateUpdate()
    {

        RaycastHit[] hits;
        hits = Physics.RaycastAll(transform.position,transform.forward, 100.0F);
        RaycastHit Hit = hits[0];
        RaycastHit aber;
        Ray rayo = Camera.main.ScreenPointToRay(Input.mousePosition);
        newpos = hits.Length;

        if (Physics.Raycast(rayo, out aber, 100))


            Debug.DrawLine(rayo.origin, aber.point);


        if (Input.GetMouseButtonDown(1))
        {

            Debug.Log(":" + newpos);

            Debug.Log("este" + newpos);
            Hit = hits[newpos];
            Instantiate(bar, Hit.transform.position, Hit.transform.rotation);


        }







    }
}`
```

Continuamente me aparece un error diciendo esto: IndexOutOfRangeException: Index was outside the bounds of the array.

Answer (score 0):

Los arrays empiezan in index 0. Si utilizas la propiedad length siempre la ultima iteracion te dara error pues .length comienza por 1. Debes restar 1 a .length.

newPos = hits.lenght -1.